# Is there any 'Click' or 'Enter' event on the ace editor autocomplete popup list?

Tags: ace-editor

I want to get the element that has been clicked from the autocomplete popup.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Ace uses dom as canvas, and doesn't use it for storing data https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/master/lib/ace/autocomplete.js#L67

Comment: @auser  I actually want to retrieve the item selected from the autocomplete popup. So I was checking if there is a click or enter event which would return the item selected from the popup.

Comment: you can try overriding insertMatch method, but depending on what you want to do with the item, there may be a better way.

Comment: @auser I have tried to override the insert match and it is not helping me wth it. Can u help me with the code?

Comment: what do you want to do in the overridden function? i can't help much with the code, if your question doesn't have any code or detailed description

Comment: @auser When the user clicks on the item from the autocomplete popup, I want to get the field of the item clicked.

To get the item clicked I'm trying to check if there is any click event

Comment: please show how did you try to override insertMatch, just saying it didn't work is not useful http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/

Comment: @auser
'insertMatch: function(editor, data) {
    editor.completer.insertMatch({value: data.caption})
})'
I used this from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/2437

Comment: Thanks @auser found the answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the popup selected item, from the insertMatch, by adding the insertMatch into the completor:

```
  callback(null,
      wordList.map(function (word) {
          return {
              caption: word,
              value: word,
              completer: {
                  insertMatch: function (editor, data) {
                      console.log("Item clicked: ", data.value);
                      editor.completer.insertMatch({value: data.name});
                  }
              }
       }
```

Comment: completer is stopping the value being appended to the editor. it just consoles and returns.

Comment: The user selected word is not being appended on to the ace editor?

Comment: My scenario was different, hence i am using editor.session.replace() which takes in range and a string as a parameter and appends the string at a desired location

Comment: Yeah just get the value using data.value and do an editor.session.replace(). In the example, I have just put console.log for just showing the word to the user. Apart from the solution should work well for you :)

Comment: Hm... In ace-builds the "Completion" interface has no "completer" field, but still functional if you assign it like "(completion as any).completer =..."

Answer (score 0):

Using @Harsha pps 's answer - I also had to add the following to get the word selected word to the editor (and remove the characters typed so far):

```
editor.removeWordLeft();
editor.insert(data.value);
```

`insertMatch` might be a better solution, as suggested by @a user, but I was unable to get this working